# Grunt: Destination [src path] not written because no source files were found

Tags: magento2, grunt

Currently working with a Magento 2.2.0 theme I made from scratch and I am using Grunt task runner to compile the LESS files to css.

Theme structure in `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme_name>` is as follows:
[theme structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdIvI.jpg)

```js
<theme alias>: {
    area: 'frontend',
    name: '<vendor>/<theme>',
    locale: 'en_US',
    files: [
        'css/styles'
    ],
    dsl: 'less'
}
```

As I try to run `grunt exec:<theme alias>`, I always get the following error:

`jit-grunt: Plugin for the "&&" task not found.
If you have installed the plugin already, please setting the static mapping.
See https://github.com/shootaroo/jit-grunt#static-mappings`

and this is for every part of the code that runs in the background for the specific task. Happens even with `sudo`. And yeah, I did clean assets beforehand + cache is disabled at all times.

Further on, running `grunt less:<theme alias>` gets me:

`>> Destination pub/static/frontend/<vendor>/<theme_name>/en_US/css/styles.css not written because no source files were found.`

Running same command with -v (verbose) flag:

```html
Loading "grunt-contrib-less" plugin

Registering "/var/www/html/mage/node_modules/grunt-contrib-less/tasks" tasks.
Loading "less.js" tasks...OK
+ less

Running "less:<theme alias>" (less) task
Verifying property less.<theme alias> exists in config...OK
Files: [no src] -> pub/static/frontend/<vendor>/<theme_name>/en_US/css/styles.css
Options: banner="", sourceMap, strictImports=false, sourceMapRootpath="/", dumpLineNumbers=false, ieCompat=false
>> Destination pub/static/frontend/<vendor>/<theme_name>/en_US/css/styles.css not written because no source files were found.

Done.
```

Grunt versions:

`grunt-cli v1.2.0
grunt v1.0.1`

Had an idea that it could have something to do with permissions at some point when these tasks run, although tried running every command with `sudo` and fixing permissions to 777, but it's the same error (`Destination not written...`) for every theme assets there.

While trying to do same in Magento 2.1, there are no errors.

Goal here is to run `grunt watch`, but the only way I can somehow style the theme is to delete pub/static after every change in LESS, let the Magento do its asset compiling and refresh the browser although I want back the workflow with `grunt watch`.

How do I fix this?
Thanks in advance, hope this is verbose enough.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your node version needs updated. This is why you are getting the error `jit-grunt: Plugin for the "&&" task not found.` A newer language construct is being used by grunt which is not supported by your version of node. I'm not sure what the minimum required version is but I can confirm it works with v8.11.1.

At your first setup of your project, at the first grunt run `grunt exec`.
This sets up everything grunt needs. After the exec task has run, you can run `grunt less` and `grunt watch`.

*`grunt less` will not work until after `grunt exec` has run.*